# Create Outlook profile with windows/outlook credentials

Tags: active-directory, exchange, domain, outlook, roaming-profile

With windows roaming profiles, most of the windows profile can roam to other computers in a domain, this includes the outlook profile.

We are moving away from roaming profiles in favor of UEV and work folders. UEV allows certain app data to roam including outlook credentials, but it does not roam the outlook profile.

I'm wondering if any know of a way or has an idea about how to use those credentials through powershell/automation to create the outlook profile.

I would also be okay with not roaming the profile but AT LEAST prompting the user with their correct email credentials. Currently they are prompted with their UPN (user principle name) from the domain which is different from their actual email address.

Thank you

Edit:

- Our domain is corpB.example.com
- The user upn is username@corpB.example.com
- The user's email should be username@example.com
- The exchange server is not part of our domain, but I think its part of corpA.example.com

There is a semi-centralized org structure. Where a primary IT department offers some centralized services like exchange. And we have our own domains (subdomains) that can use those services.

Comment: You mentioned that the email is a different domain than the user, but are the user accounts joined to the same domain as the Exchange Server?

Comment: @CoryKnutson I've edited my original post to try to answer that. (i'm new to sysadministration)

Comment: It answers my question about the Active directory domain being different for the Exchange server and the users. Do you know if `corpA.example.com` and `corpB.example.com` are in a shared forest or have a trust between them?

Comment: no they are not in the same forest and don't have a trust between them

Comment: ZeroConfigExchange is a registry setting that may work, but it would require at least a trust, and the auto-discover to be fully functional. I have used it to automate configuration of mail profiles with users in the same domain as Exchange. It may be worth some research.

Comment: @CoryKnutson thanks for the suggestion. But ZeroConfigExchange doesnt really address this issue. It simplifies outlook profile configuration for the user, but doesn't change the default username (UPN) in the credentials prompt.
I appreciate the suggestions though

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional UPN suffixes in `Active directory Domains and Trusts` to be able to make the UPN match the email in most cases. Then you can change the UPN in `Active Directory Users and Computers` or in batches via Powershell.

[image]

Comment: I have seen this solution BUT I am not sure the ramifications of doing that because we have quite a few 3rd party AD integrations.

Thank you, but I really looking for any other alternative to that approach :)